# How to avoid Polymer element's AttributeChanged event calling Multiple times

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymer

Actually I am using Polymer elements `A` ,`B` , `C` and `D` in my Application. Consider the below scenario.

> 1) Element A has boolean attribute named 'devEnable' 
>   2) Element A has attributeChanged event named 'devEnableChanged'
>   3) And my business logic is implemented in 'devEnableChanged' event 
>   4) Other elements --> B extends A  , C extends A , D extends A

Now I run my application, when the attribute `devEnable` is changed to true or false then `devEnableChanged` event is getting fired 3 times because of this my business logic also is getting fired 3 times. So I want to avoid firing `devEnableChanged` event multiple times.

Is there any way to avoid calling it multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a base polymer element(A) as kind of composition within a template tag of a former derived polymer element(B, C or D) is an option instead of heritage:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="derived-element.html">
</head>
<body>

    <derived-element id="derivedElement" value="3546"></derived-element>
    <input type="button" id="assignBaseElementButton" value="assign base"/>
    <input type="button" id="assignDerivedElementButton" value="assign derived"/>
    <input type="text" id="valueField"/>

</body>
<script>

    document.getElementById('assignDerivedElementButton').addEventListener('click',function(){

        var derivedElement = document.querySelector('#derivedElement');

        var textFieldValue = document.getElementById('valueField').value;

        // get derived element's attribute value to assign it to a value of valueField textfield
        derivedElement.value = textFieldValue;

    });

    document.getElementById('assignBaseElementButton').addEventListener('click',function(){

        var derivedElement = document.querySelector('#derivedElement');

        var textFieldValue = document.getElementById('valueField').value;

        // get base element's attribute value to assign it to a value of valueField textfield 
        derivedElement.getBaseElement().value = textFieldValue;

    });

</script>
</html>
```

derived-element.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/base-element.html">
<polymer-element name="derived-element" attributes="value">
    <template>
        <!-- embed base element here -->
        <base-element id="baseElement"></base-element>
        <div>
            derived element'value: {{value}}
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('derived-element',{
            value: null,
            ready:function(){
                this.getBaseElement().baseValue = this.value;
            },
            // watcher for value property
            valueChanged: function(oldvalue, newvalue) {

                // this method is called once
                console.log('my-element', 'oldvalue: ',oldvalue, ' newvalue: ',newvalue);

            },
            getBaseElement:function(){
                return this.$.baseElement;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

base-element:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="base-element">
    <template>
        <span>Hello from <b>base-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM. And my value is {{value}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('base-element',{
            value: null,
            // watcher for value property
            valueChanged: function(oldvalue, newvalue) {

                // this method is called once
                console.log('base-element', 'oldvalue: ',oldvalue, ' newvalue: ',newvalue);

            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```